# fatal: cannot exec '/home/<user>/.ssh': Permission denied when using Git

Tags: git, ssh

when I try to do a `pull`, `push` or `clone` with Git using SSH auth I get this error:

```
$ git clone ssh://user@server:<repos>.git
Cloning into '<repos>'...
fatal: cannot exec '/home/<user>/.ssh': Permission denied
fatal: unable to fork
```

I've already copied the public key to the server and can even log into server using SSH.

I've already tried to reinstall Git, tried to change public key on server and use `sudo` with `git clone`, but none of this worked.

The 'funny' part is: it was working a couple of days ago. I was using Git with command line, then tried to use Git with Eclipse, manage to solve some errors, and then Git stopped working on Eclipse and command line.

Why I get this error with Git but when I try to log on the server don't?

Comment: Something in the config is screwed. It's trying to exec a directory. Maybe look for an `ssh` which got changed into `.ssh`.

Comment: Solved.
When trying to solve some errors with Eclipse and Git, I had to set a `$GIT_HOME` variable on `.profile` file.
Deleting this variable solved the problem.
Thank you @tripleee for helping me find this!

Comment: Please post as an answer and accept it, so that this question no longer comes up as unresolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When trying to solve some errors with Eclipse and Git, I had to set a `$GIT_HOME=/home/<user>/.ssh` variable on `~/.profile` file.
Deleting this variable solved the problem.

Comment: Same story here with $GIT_SSH variable but I had that in ~/.bashrc. I had to unset the variable and delete the it too